# Generate serial keys Node.js duplication issue

Tags: node.js

I am using Node.js to generate serial keys using following formula

```
yydddmmssMiMi
```

where yy is year with in 2 digits, ddd day of year e.g feb 1 is 032, mm minutes, ss seconds, MiMi milliseconds
031122312. here is sample code

```
exports.generateSerialKey = async () => {

  const date = new Date();
  const year = date.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2);
  const day = dateOfYear();
  const hours = formatDate(date.getHours(), 2);
  let minutes = parseInt((new Date()).getMinutes(), 10);
  minutes = formatDate(minutes, 2);
  let seconds = parseInt((new Date()).getSeconds(), 10);
  seconds = formatDate(seconds, 2);
  await sleep(19);
  let milliseconds = Math.floor((new Date()).getMilliseconds());
  milliseconds = formatDate(milliseconds, 2).substr(0, 2);

  return  `${year}${day}${hours}${minutes}${seconds}${milliseconds}`;
 };
```

But problem is when I hit same API simultaneously, serial keys are being repeated.I have to generate more than 10000 serial keys in a loop

Comment: Is it necessary to have such format of serial-key?

Comment: Yes that's business requirement, total length of serial key is 20 btw.

Comment: And it is necessary to have only digits included in serial key?

Comment: Yes @ArtemArkhipov here is complete formula ```${companyCode}${packingLevel}${companyLine}${year}${day}${hours}${minutes}${seconds}${milliseconds}``` explanation of formula:  ```4 companycode+1packing level+2 line code+2 year(like 18)+3 day of year (like 324 day of year)+2 hours(like 22 or 23 or 09)+2 minutes+2 seconds+2 miliseconds```

Comment: Key, generated via this formula can not guarantee uniqueness because it depends only on time. Moreover it is very easy to predict.

Answer (score 2):

So, after conversation in comments, here is my answer. Hope it will suit you.

As we mentioned in comments now you have requirements from your management to use formula of serial key which consists of 20 symbols:

```
${companyCode}${packingLevel}${companyLine}${year}${day}${hours}${minutes}${seconds}${milliseconds}
```

Unfortunately, keys generated via this formula don't guarantee uniqueness in any way, as they totally depend just on the date and time. Moreover such keys can be easily predicted.

You next question was:

> So what can I recommend to my management to avoid this?

Fortunately there is already solution for this task and it even has some [standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

For using with nodeJS I'd recommend npm [module uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid).

Simple example of the code:

```
const uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');
uuidv4(); // ⇨ '10ba038e-48da-487b-96e8-8d3b99b6d18a'
```

Such approach will be much more reliable, secure and convenient.
If for some reason they will still need length of the key to be 20 symbols - you may, probably, use just a part of longer uuid or google some other non-standard approaches to generate such string.

Comment: This is a good answer. One question, any reason to use this over the builtin crypto library? `require('crypto').randomBytes(10).toString("hex")` would generate a 20 character, securely random string. I suppose the dashes make it easier for a human to read / enter?

Comment: Crypto is usually used for different purposes like hashing passwords, etc. Probably it could suit here, but I decided to use more common library for this in my example.